# Can someone translate whats on this pendant? (Character identified: 醒)

Tags: character-identification

[image]

This is a Chinese pendant but i cant figure out what it says at all.

Answer (score 1):

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E9%86%92)

> 醒
>   xǐng
>   to wake up / to be awake / to become aware / to sober up / to come to

---

How to find your answer:

You could use a site like: [mdbg](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary) (click the handwriting button next to "Go") or [qhanzi](https://www.qhanzi.com/) to write in your character and then copy and paste into a dictionary.